# C++ Conversion Operator Overloading issue

Tags: operator-overloading, type-conversion

I have my own SmartPointer class.

There are cases where SmartPtr contain a class that inherite from a Base class, and I would like to convert `SmartPtr<ClassX> into SmartPtr<BaseClassOfClassX>;`

I am trying to overload the SmartPtr Conversion operator to do this.

It work fine for the Class themself, such as:

```
template<class newType>
operator SmartPtr<newType>() const
{
    return SmartPtr<newType>((SmartPtr<newType>*)this);
}
```

but not for pointer to the Class, I have tried the following, and it never gets call and get the following error:

```
template<class newType>
operator SmartPtr<newType>*() const
{
        return static_cast<SmartPtr<newType>*>(this);
}
```

Simple code to get the error:

```
    SmartPtr<ClassX> test(pClassX);
    SmartPtr<BaseClassOfClassX>* ob = &test;

ERROR:
cannot convert from 'SmartPtr<T> *' to 'SmartPtr<T> *'
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with my second conversion overload?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ standard: "*An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one
parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.*"

As the type of `&test` is not a class nor anything implicitly convertible to a class, you cannot overload the typecasts on the pointer directly.  Depending on why you need pointers to your smart pointers, maybe you really want to employ references which is much more common.